# How can I make git merge produce more granular conflicts when using `merge.conflictstyle diff3`?

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I have a problem with an, in my opinion, unintuitive merge behavior of git (version 2.31.1). Let me demonstrate with a small toy repo.

```
git init
touch file1
git add file1
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git branch feature
```

Now I have a commit with an empty file and two branches, `main` and `feature`, pointing to that commit. Now I change the file in the main branch to

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

and commit the change with

```
git add file1
git commit -m "Change file1"
```

Next, I go to the other branch

```
git checkout feature
```

change `file1` there to

```
line1
line2
line
line4
line5
```

and again commit the change with

```
git add file1
git commit -m "Change file1"
```

The resulting commit tree looks like this:

```
* b1beb63 - Change file1 (HEAD -> feature)
| * 32ea83d - Change file1 (main)
|/
* 2952256 - Initial commit
```

Now I switch back to the `main` branch and merge `feature` into `main`.

```
git checkout main
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
git merge feature
```

As expected, there is a conflict in `file1`. However, the conflict looks like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
||||||| 2952256
=======
line1
line2
line
line4
line5
>>>>>>> feature
```

As you can see, git acts like the entire file is one large conflict. I would have expected it to look like this:

```
line1
line2
<<<<<<< HEAD
line3
||||||| 2952256
=======
line
>>>>>>> feature
line4
line5
```

which would be infinitely more user-friendly.

I found some threads where people had similar problems because of different line endings. **This is not the case here** as I edited the file in both branches on the same platform with the same editor.

My current solution for this type of merge is to find changes manually by doing a diff of the files between the two branches, i.e. `git diff main:file1 feature:file1`. This works, but is rather annoying.

**Is there any way to get the behavior I would expect in this merge? If not, is there any good reason why this is not possible?**

Comment: This problem is specific to the diff3 merge.conflictStyle. Without that it does what you want.

Comment: @Schwern That's true, but then I will not have the benefits of the diff3 conflict style. In this trivial example it does not matter, but in general I'd like to stick to the diff3 conflict style.

Comment: I've got it down to a straightforward explanation why you can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git 2.35.0 will have a new conflict style that behaves exactly as desired here called `zdiff3`. It can be configured with `git config merge.conflictstyle zdiff3`. Add `--global` to configure the conflict style globally.

I tested it with git version `2.35.0.rc0` and it produces the following result.

```
line1
line2
<<<<<<< HEAD
line3
||||||| 59df1b4
=======
line
>>>>>>> feature
line4
line5
```

Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** Your expected behavior is an invalid diff3 representation of the conflict. You can't have both.

---

[The original commit explains in excruciating detail](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83133740d9c81ce4c98cb53b85c8d5b190944f81). I'll try to summarize.

Let's look at your case. You started with this.

```
# ancestor

# main
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5

# feature
line1
line2
line
line4
line5
```

You asked for a diff between all three files, and that's what you got.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
||||||| 2952256
=======
line1
line2
line
line4
line5
>>>>>>> feature
```

The original file is blank. HEAD changed it to added five lines. feature added five lines. That's a correct representation of the 3-way conflict.

Let's look at what you expect to see...

```
line1
line2
<<<<<<< HEAD
line3
||||||| 2952256
=======
line
>>>>>>> feature
line4
line5
```

This says ***the original file contained 4 lines***. HEAD and feature added a line between line2 and line4.

In other words, it says you merged these files.

```
# ancestor
line1
line2
line4
line5

# main
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5

# feature
line1
line2
line
line4
line5
```

That is not true, the ancestor was blank.

The reduction you want is fine for 2-way conflict markers, but would defeat the point of 3-way conflict markers.

Comment: I guess that explains exactly why diff3 behaves this way. In that case I'd like to see another conflict style that gives me what I want. I don't see a fundamental problem with the conflict style that I suggested.

Comment: There isn't a fundamental problem with the conflict style you're suggesting. The default style shows you just the different lines in the two tips, the diff3 style shows you the different changes in the two tips, you want a hybrid. I think all merge tools already show you that on steroids, all four versions (base, ours, theirs, conflicted) with the differing lines highlighted appropriately. But there's times when you really do need a diff3, showing the full extent of the changes in each tip.

Comment: @ntv1000 You need something more flexible. A good IDE (Visual Studio Code, Atom, JetBrains) will have its own visual merge conflict tool. Or you can use [`git-mergetool`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool) to choose any number of existing merge utilities to resolve conflicts. See "External Merge and Diff Tools" in [Customizing Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration).

Comment: Someone is working on a third merge-conflict-display algorithm, tentatively called "zdiff3", that lets Git do what it can and shows the remaining diff in diff3 style. Whether it will handle this particular case, I don't know.